# Div slide up when click in items inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, document, slideup

I have a `div` that slides down (opens) when I click a certain input select. Inside this `div`, I have some other input selects and my objective is to slide up the `div` when I click on the rest of the page.

#### My problem:

The `div` slides up when I select some item in the input selects inside it, and I don't want this to happen.

- Is there some way to slide up the `div` only when I click outside it?
- Why are the selects inside the div making it to slide up as well?

This is my javascript to slide up the div:

```
$(document).mouseup(function (e) {
  var container = $('.myDiv');
  if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $(container).removeClass('close');
    $(container).addClass('open');
    $(container).next().slideUp(200);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The div slides up when I select some item in the input selects inside
>   it, and I don't want this to happen.
>
> Is there some way to slide up the div only when I click outside it?
>   Why are the selects inside the div making it to slide up as well?

Use [**event.stopPropagation()**](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) on the child element(s) to prevent the slide event being triggered by them.

> event.stopPropagation - Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM
>   tree, preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

Here's a simple [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wxHGs/1/) and the basic example below.

**jQuery:**

```
$('div').click(function(){
  $('#slideMeUp').slideUp();
});

$('select').click(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>Clicking here will trigger it! 
    <select>
        <option>This won't trigger the click event anymore!</option>
    </select>
    Clicking here will also trigger it!
</div>

<div id="slideMeUp">Only clicking the outer div will slide me up!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check you `e.target.id` with your `container` id

```
        $(document).mouseup(function (e) {
            var container = $('.myDiv');
            if(e.target.id==$(this).attr('id'))
            {
            if (container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
                $(container).removeClass('close');
                $(container).addClass('open');
                $(container).next().slideUp(200);
            }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest binding `mousedown` rather than `mouseup`. There are inconsistencies in behaviour between browsers, this **may** have something to do with your issue.

You should also add some logic to check the clicked element isn't the `div` itself, clicking just outside of an `input`, but still inside of the `div` would currently cause the `slideUp` to occur.

```
if (!container.has(e.target).length && !container.is(e.target)) {
  ...
}
```

Other than that, it should work fine.

#### [Have a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/CCa46/1/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's specific items that are causing problems, perhaps something like this?

On click tell it to to slideUp your div as long as the clicked item is "not" in the list.

```
('body').click(function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).is('#id_of_item .class_to_ignore')) {
    var container = $('.myDiv');
    $(container).removeClass('close');
    $(container).addClass('open');
    $(container).next().slideUp(200);
  }
});
```